# Создаение директори themes в Laravel. Проблема с Auth::routes();

Tags: php, laravel, auth, themes

Попытался создать директорию themes
1. AppServiceProvider добавил

```
$this->app['view']->addNamespace('theme', base_path() . '/resources/themes/' . config('app.theme', 'default'));
```

2.В .env Добавил

```
 APP_THEME=default
```

3.Для вывода представления нужно всего добавить префикс theme

```
 return view('theme::home.index');
```

Как можно изменить путь для view файлов, для роута Auth::routes();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В контроллерах `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` нужно переопределить методы трейтдов например для LoginController пример.

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('new_views');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все четко получилось!!

Comment: Отметьте ответ пожалуйста